# File ordering in ckeditor file browser in Liferay 6.2

Tags: ckeditor, liferay-6

When browsing resources in ckeditor in Liferay 6.2, files appear unordered, making difficult to fetch one of them. That was not the behaviour in Liferay 6.1, where files where ordered by name.

Any way to fix this? Is it possible to sort them other way, as for instance by descending date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an older question however I came across this problem the last week and I did not find any solution either on the internet.

So I implemented a hook to enable sorting by the name of the file.

To enable sorting by date you have to create an ext-plugin to provide the dates (created, modified) to the file browser and after that you can modify the display with a hook (eventually the same ordering hook as above).

You can find a detailed description how I achieved it here: http://hahamo.wordpress.com/2015/02/10/ordering-files-in-the-ckeditor-file-browser-with-liferay/